# Exponents in Modular Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am having a hard time simplifying the problem below. This is a practice problem from my text book. The book did not explain the concept enough so I am having trouble.

Problem:

$8^{202}$ mod 10

Comment: Have you learned the chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: No. The book talks about Eulers Method though

Comment: Eulers Theorem*

Comment: Euler's Theorem isn't enough for this problem.  Any other tools you were given?

Comment: @Mike Actually Euler or little Fermat suffices if you combine the result with parity - see my answer, which avoids both by directly noting that $\,8^2\equiv -1,\,$ so $\,8^{4n}\equiv 1\pmod{5}\ \ $

Comment: How did you get the 4n? Is the 4n equal to the amount of solutions? (8, 4, 2, 6)

Comment: @Binary By generalizing your problem, which  has exponent $\,4n\!+\!2\,$ for $\,n=50.\ $ Here $4$ is the period of the repeating powers.

Answer (score 2):

This would be the last digit of $8^{202}$. Essentially it asks for the remainder when the number is divided by $10$ in this case. All numbers which leave the same remainder would be considered equivalent to each other.

Here note that $8^1=8, 8^2=4, 8^3=2, 8^4=6, 8^5=8, ...$ all mod $10$. You can notice a pattern soon enough and conclude. Also each time, all you need to worry is the last digit, you don't have to multiply the whole number.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I am still confused

Comment: Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ {\rm mod}\ 5\!:\ \color{#c00}{8^2\equiv -1}\ $ so $\ x := 8^{4n+2}\equiv (\color{#c00}{8^2})^{2n+1}\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^{2n+1}\equiv -1\equiv \color{#0a0}4$

Thus, mod $\,10\!:\ x\equiv \color{#0a0}4\,$ or $\,\color{#0a0}4+5.\,$ It must be $\,x\equiv 4\,$ since $\,x\,$ is even. $ \ $ **QED**

Answer (score 0):

$$8\equiv-2,8^2\equiv(-2)^2\equiv4,8^3\equiv(-2)4\equiv2,8^4\equiv(4)^2\equiv6\pmod{10}$$

$$202\equiv2\pmod4\implies 8^{202}\equiv8^2\equiv?$$

---

Alternatively,

as $(8,10)=2,$ let use start with $8^{201}\pmod{\dfrac{10}2}$

$8\equiv3,8^2\equiv-1,8^4\equiv1\pmod5$ (which is also available from Fermat's Little Theorem )

As $201\equiv1\pmod4,8^{201}\equiv8^1\pmod5\equiv3$

$\implies8^{202}\equiv8\cdot3\pmod{8\cdot5}\equiv24\pmod{40}\equiv24\pmod{10}\equiv4$

See Property $\#9$ of [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html)